# Share mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, sharing

I'm looking for share database from two server into one server, for sample that there is one mysql database server relate to shopping database from hostgator.com and there is two shopping websites server from other hosting company NOT from hostgator company, my question is that is this possible to login in into other company sever use that database from other two from shopping site server from other company!

If possible how, do we can use that! what do we called this! is there is website that i can learn more!

many thanks.

Comment: Yes. Create a user with a host of your secondary server and allow remote access in my.cnf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
$con = new mysqli ("SERVER_IP","db_user","db_pass","db");
```

Instead of

```
$con = new mysqli ("localhost",...);
```

You need to create a user for the database with host % permissions and you need to allow remote access to the database, see here:

[enable remote access](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html)

Hope this was what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Any application can directly use any database if the application can "see" that database.  What this means includes, but is not limited to:

- Both the application and the database and currently running
- The hosts running the application and the database can reach each other over a network
- The database *service* is reachable by the application over the network
- Necessary ports aren't blocked
- Necessary permissions are enabled
- etc.

As long as there doesn't exist a condition by which one instance can't "see" the other (such as a firewall preventing host and/or port access) then it makes no difference what hosts the application and database are on.  It's just a change to the connection string.

*However*, if there *does* exist such a condition (such as a blocked port, which would be very common in this scenario) and the database *isn't* "visible" to the application, then you have two options:

1. Correct the condition (for example, open the port)
2. Create an intermediary API

In many cases, particularly where you don't own the network infrastructure being used, the first option may not be possible.  (Even if you do own the network infrastructure, it may not be *advisable* for security reasons.  Internet-accessible databases are generally frowned upon unless you really understand the security of that database.)

So in the event that you need to create an API, this would simply be an additional application which *can* see the database (possibly running on the same host, or within the same firewall) and which exposes functionality that *is* visible (such as a web service instead of direct database access).  It can be very simple, exposing just get/save ([CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete)) functionality to the database.  Or it can be more intelligent, exposing business operations over the data which external clients can use.  It's up to you.